# Should we count duplicate badges separately?

Tags: discussion, badges

I like my badges on SO - proper. But it tells me I have 50 bronze badges. Of these 50, 17 are the same! They are the "Popular Question" badge. I'm sure John Skeet has oodles of these, maybe thousands.

Maybe I'm just too gamified, but I'd like to  know how many *unique* badges I have. Maybe it's the Pokemon collector in me.

So does anyone else agree? That they are curious about the unique count, but not duplicate?

Comment: You mean, for instance, showing "X different badges" on your profile page?

Comment: Right there, on [Jon Skeet's profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) it says he has 595 badges. That's the unique badge count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And if you want the other number 8,857 you [look at the badge activity page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=activity&sort=badges)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't downvote to disagree since it is not really a "feature request".  But I disagree.

This isn't a "Gotta Get 'em All" type thing.  The badges help measure your contributions to the site, so if I answer one question and get 10 upvotes, and Jon Skeet provides 1000 answers that get 10 upvotes each, why shouldn't he get 999 more badges than me since his contributions were 1000x more than mine.

There aren't that many badges that you can't easily scan the badge page to see why you are missing.  the badge page can be your "Pokedex".

Comment: I love the Pokemon references in this question.

Answer (score 2):

As Jamal and Martijn Pieters noted, you can easily see this on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763029). You have currently 50 badges and 39 *unique* badges:

> [image]

**EDIT**

ERRATUM: 50 bronze badges and 39 *unique* badges **all categories**.

Comment: I seemed to confuse myself with my comment, though.  Indeed the profile shows the unique badges, while the count on the top page bar is your total count.

Comment: @Jamal I confess that I'm lost. I'm not sure I understand exactly the meaning of the question. I will go to sleep and check it tomorrow :)

Comment: It's a clusterf*ck of confusion. :-) I did look at my badge count on CR, so this holds true (with the edit correction).

Answer (score 0):

Quantity over quality! A lot of badges from the same type doesn't equal to a lot of badges from exactly one category/badge.

That's why I think it's unnecessary.